# How can i deal with DLL files in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I want to improve my programs by using dll files next to the application or using libraries of the operating system..

So how can i pack classes into **dll** file in C# ?

and how can i call methodes from **dll** files ?

Comment: Can you please explain WHY this would improve your program? Nonetheless, what you do is that you divide your visual studio solution into multiple `class libraries`. This is ONLY useful if you reuse this DLLs at any point or redistribute them

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, but start a Class Library project in visual studio , put all the classes in it, compile it and you will get a dll , next you can add reference to that dll in your other project and start using its classes/methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how can I pack classes into dll file in C# ?

Make a **library project** from visual studio project templates. When you will compile it, you will get dll in the output folder (probably the **debug** folder).

> How can I call methods from dll files ?

Add a reference of this project where you want to consume the *library* (dll) and use its class. Do not forget to import the **namespace** for more ease.

Comment: what is the syntax of the reference please ?
how can i write it ?

Comment: If you are asking about reference then you have to click references folder in project you want to add and then select the project for project tab, going through this article will make this much clearer http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s16p1.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your own managed DLL, you can make a *class library* project in Visual Studio. That will create a DLL that you can reference from other projects.

If you want to call native code in a DLL from managed code, you can use the [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Visual Studio class-library project-type:

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d11h6832%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).